# Prevent Development modules from being added to configuration management

Tags: 8, configuration

We have modules that are only used for local development like [Stage File Proxy](https://www.drupal.org/project/stage_file_proxy). How would I prevent these modules from being added to the configuration management?

Comment: No idea on the real answer, but as a workaround you could gitignore the configuration output of these modules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Dave Reid on Twitter](https://twitter.com/davereid/status/749295832487366656)

**Ignoring Development Modules**

If you have a certain list of modules that should only be enabled on the development or staging server, then this may be done with the built-in --skip-modules option in the config-export and config-import commands.

For example, if you want to enable the 'devel' module on development systems, but not on production server, you could define the following configuration settings in your drushrc.php file:

```
# $command_specific['config-export']['skip-modules'] = array('devel');
# $command_specific['config-import']['skip-modules'] = array('devel');
```

You may then use drush pm-enable to enable the devel module on the development machine, and subsequent imports of the configuration data will not cause it to be disabled again. Similarly, if you make changes to configuration on the development environment and export them, then the devel module will not be listed in the exports.

http://www.drush.org/en/master/config-exporting/#ignoring-development-modules

Comment: Thanks this worked. At first I thought this wasn't working but it turns out that the configuration file still gets created but it doesn't add the module to  `core.extension.yml` so the module won't get enabled on other environment!

Comment: Actually I don't think this worked.  All it does is not add the module to  `core.extension.yml` and if someone runs the `drush cim -y` command without having the module enabled they get the following error (see below comment):

Comment: `Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporterException: There were errors validating the config synchronization. in Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporter->validate() (line[error]
728 of /var/www/xmd8/www/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigImporter.php).
The import failed due for the following reasons: `

Comment: `Configuration <em class="placeholder">devel.settings</em> depends on the <em class="placeholder">Devel</em> module that will not be installed after import.
Configuration <em class="placeholder">stage_file_proxy.settings</em> depends on the <em class="placeholder">Stage File Proxy</em> module that will not be
installed after import.`

Comment: This is the correct answer. There is an issue with Drush that is causing this: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1820